# ForEachLoop not working in PowerShell, but I have full access what is the issue?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, azure-ad-graph-api, powershell-ise

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9nqY.png)

```
 Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$count
#$farm = Get-SPFarm
$siteList = Get-SPSite -Limit 1
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext($siteList[0])
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($servicecontext)
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()
foreach ($hi in $profiles) {
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($hi["AboutMe"].Value) -eq $false){
        write-host "Acount Name:"$hi.AccountName"|AboutMe:"$hi["AboutMe"].Value
        $count++
    }
}
write-host $count
```

I keep getting errors with the foreachloop, the following error. When I type SP-Farm, I get everything back so it can't be an access issue?

```
UserProfileDBCache_WCFLogging :: ProfileDBCacheServiceClient.GetUserData threw exception: Access is denied.
At line:8 char:10
+ foreach ($hi in $profiles) {
+          ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following PowerShell for your reference.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$count
$siteList = Get-SPSite -Limit 1
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext($siteList[0])
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext)
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()
foreach ($profile in $profiles) {
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($profile["AboutMe"].Value) -eq $false){
        write-host "Acount Name:"$profile.AccountName"|AboutMe:"$profile["AboutMe"].Value
        $count++
    }
}
write-host $count
```

[image]